# How do you paint over copper?

Tags: painting, paint

The top of a bay window I have is covered with a metal sheet.  The patina and color of the corrosion on it suggests that it might be painted copper.

What sort of paint should I use to freshen up this sheet?

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to paint it or would you rather bring back it's natural beauty?

Comment: Peter, take a look at the edit. You really need to use an oil-based primer. The previous picture was for the water-based primer which I would not recommend for this project.

Comment: @Jerry_Contrary You said "oil based" in your text (which I agree with) so I sort of ignored the link and picture :D

Comment: Unless my eyes deceive me, this copper roof feature is partially under an eave, meaning the outer part of it is constantly nailed with dripping rain, and the rest is not.  Because of the asymmetrical treatment, you will never get a proper patina out of that. Regrettably paint is your only option.

Comment: @Harper If my gutters work as they should then I shouldn't have any patina at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking about painting the copper:

- Wash the surface well and scrape off any loose debris.
- Prime the surface with an oil-based primer such as [**Zinsser Cover Stain**](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Zinsser-Cover-Stain-VOC-High-Hide-Oil-Base-Interior-Exterior-Stain-Blocker-Primer/20512770)
- Apply two top coats of the exterior paint of your choice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### It's more about the *prep*

The key to a successful painting is getting the paint to stick.  The right paint does nothing if it fails to adhere.

By "succesful painting" I mean a job you won't have to re-do every couple of years.

You do all the usual light scraping to get the loose stuff off.  But for the final prep pass, go at it with Scotchbrite pads.   Obligatory huge product shot here.

[image]

You're not trying to *polish* it, however you are trying to assure everything gets covered with microscopic scratches, and anything thick enough to present an adhesion/separation problem is gone.

Of course, if you accidentally did polish it, you could coat it with an oil-based **varnish** to keep it from oxidizing.

After sweeping away any particles/dust, oil is your remaining enemy.   Your final step of prep is to wipedown in solvent (whatever the paint solvent is, typically paint thinner).  If it's water based (I'm not a fan of water-based for challenging jobs), then wash it with soap and water, thoroughly rinsed.

Then follow with your **primer** of choice, then topcoat.  I'll never be a fan of "primer and topcoat in one can" products.  There's only one paint formulation that does that well, a **2-part epoxy** such as Amercote (don't bother, it's not for consumers), and epoxy is allergic to sunlight so it needs a topcoat to stop it from quickly failing.  Generally primers don't give you a choice of color.

If your ultimate destination is a dark color, Rustoleum 7769 Rusty Metal Primer is *actually made to prime metal*, and is readily available.

[image]